# How is Cloud Functions for Firebase different from GAE?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-queue

I am using Firebase in my App in Nodejs. I have JS API which takes imprints of website users(kind of Google Analytics) and from there it updates Data in Firebase and event Listeners binded in Nodejs compute the analytics.

**Problem:**

Currently, App is hosted on GAE and I have to manage minimum 300k concurrent connections.

I am facing issue with scaling the App, as Firebase works on sockets, so if multiple instances are working, it makes incur duplicate processing of the same request depending on the number of instances working.

Sol 1 - **Queues**: I tried using firebase-queues but it could not take the heavy load and logs to Firebase Disconnect for all the queues, as many tasks got queued which result to timeout

Sol 2 - **Cloud Functions**: I suppose cloud functions in background uses GAE, which will incur the same duplicate request issue.

How actually functions scale? does it add CPU & memory or add servers? 
Can anyone suggest me? how should I scale with Firebase? else I will be left with last option to remove Firebase and make it REST based.

Comment: If you have very broad questions like this that are are best served by some conversation, consider posting to firebase-talk instead.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/  BTW, Cloud Functions does not use GAE.  It's a whole different cloud service.